# Ionic 4 ion-list horizontal - want to show a list ion-list horizontal tabs

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, tabbar

I would like to use Ionic 4 ion-list to show a horizontal list instead of the typical vertical list. Have a look at below picture:

[image]

Let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ion-segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment)?

```
<ion-segment>
  <ion-segment-button value="dogs">
    <ion-label>Dogs</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="cats">
    <ion-label>Cats</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Comment: ios-slides is the better way then this. There are slidesPerView option in ion-slides to control the number of slide to display. So you can set height and slidesPerView in ion-slides to get horizontal list.